# How to fix 'java.sql.SQLException:[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid descriptor index' for this code

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

i can able to execute query2 commented in the following code but the query1(bold font) is showing the above error. can anyone help me out of this.

> java.sql.SQLException:[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid
>   descriptor index

```
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:mini1");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();

        **String query1="SELECT empd1.EmpNo as nn,empd2.Designation as dd FROM empd1 Inner join empd2 ON (empd1.DesignationCode = empd2.DesignationCode) ";**
        //String query2="select * from empd1 Inner join empd2 ON (empd1.DesignationCode = empd2.DesignationCode) ";
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(qry);

        while(rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + "\t" + 
                    rs.getString(2) + "\t" + 
                    rs.getString(3) + "\t" +
                    rs.getString(4) + "\t" +
                    rs.getString(5) );
                    }

        rs.close();
        st.close();
        con.close();
```

i expect to print table but actually it is displaying so-  java.sql.SQLException:[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid descriptor index

Comment: `query1` only returns two columns, `nn` and `dd`, per row of data fetched. Now look at what you're doing in your `println` statement, how many columns are you attempting to access? That's your problem.

Comment: @Satya Harsha what is the data type of your two selected columns